# How to download a website for offline reading

Tags: download, fetch

i need to download an entire website, there are a lot of programs, but my problem is that, I need to fetch the site when i am logged in. I tried multiple programs but they dont work. Is there a way?

Comment: OP wants to save an entire site, not a single page, @Biswapriyo

Comment: You should start by giving the list of programs you tried, how you used them and what were the results, "they dont work" is not a technical detailed statement. Specifying the OS you are on would also be needed (or if you are open to solutions in any of them).

Comment: How does the login work on your website? In fact which one it is ? Is it standard HTTP authentification, or a form you fill out with username and password?

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (software shopping). Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Answer (score 1):

Try HTTRACK...it's easy to use and can download entire site or any specific section of it on your desktop or your android..!!
You can get it from [Download HTTRACK](https://www.httrack.com)

Comment: Can you show which option of this tool deals with login on a website?

Comment: Though your answer is acceptable (in my eyes) some would prefer you to follow this guide, though you don't have to with this one, just for answers you make in the future: https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers